# Binding nested list in toolkit expanderView

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, windows-phone, expander

I have a small problem in my project, I'm working with Windows Phone Toolkit's ExpanderView and I can not succeed to bind nested list.

Here's the situation, I have two classes:

- Account
- PersonObj

Account class exposes three properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<PersonObj> People;
public string TotalText;
public string PeopleText;
```

PersonObj these:

```
public string Name
public string QuotaText
```

The relevant XAML is this:

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>

                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                               LineHeight="25" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding TotalText}"
                                             Foreground="Red"
                                             FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
                                             FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/> 
                                        <LineBreak/>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding PeopleText}"   
                                             Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"
                                             FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                                             FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>

                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ListBoxItem toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding People.Name}"       
                                                   Margin="0,8,0,-4"
                                                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                                                   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
                                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding People.QuotaText}"
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   Margin="0,0,0,-2"
                                                   Foreground="Red"
                                                   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
                                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
```

and I have the control in a ListView.

In the code behind I set the ListView.ItemSource

```
ListView.ItemsSource = application.Equalize.Accounts;
```

Now, it all seems to work but the two properties TotalText and PeopleText shows up but the properties of the nested class Name and QuotaText does not show.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this binding : `Binding People.Name`
You can't expect that to work because "People" property is of type List, and List doesn't has Name property in it!!

Instead, what you should be doing here is having a ItemsControl (eg: ListBox) inside ExpanderView.ItemTemplate, and then use your ListBoxItem template inside ItemTemplate of ItemsControl.

something like:

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">...
//your current code
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<toolkit: ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>...
```

It actually depends how you want to show List insider expander view. But hope you get the idea.